# Filtering a nested list of 0

Tags: python, nested, minimum

I am trying to filter a nested list of values to remove the 0 so I can calculate the minimum without 0.

```
data = [[0, 723, 124,],[4084, 208, 32, 4 ], [ 413, 277, 0, 154], [], [211, 132,0, 54]]
```

I have tried:

```
for i in data:
   new_values = []
   mins = min((i), default=0)
   if mins == 0:
      new_values = (filter(lambda x: x !=0, data))
print(new_values)
```

it gives me:

```
[]
<filter object at 0x040D4130>
[]
[]
[]
[]
<filter object at 0x040D40F0>
[]
[]
[]
[]
<filter object at 0x040D4130>
```

Expected code:

```
   data = [[723, 124,],[4084, 208, 32, 4 ], [ 413, 277, 154], [], [211, 132, 54]]
```

Expected output:

```
mins = (124, 4,154,0,54)
```

Comment: what is the expected output of this code?

Comment: `[list(filter(lambda x: x !=0, i)) for i in data]` code give you list without 0 value element

Comment: When I tried that it gave me the empty [] lists and where above it has the filter object it has the complete lists.

Comment: `[min(list(filter(lambda x: x !=0, i))) for i in data if len(i)]` complementing @VivekSable answer

Comment: Thanks. I keep forgetting the nested loop bit for i in data etc. Now I just need to figure out what to do in the nested list when it is empty []. I need it to give a 0. This way it just disappears from the minimum list.

Answer (score 1):

1. We have to iterate over the input list.
2. Remove Zero-value from each item of input data by filter and lambda function. [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-lambda?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034358&utm_targetid=aud-390929969673:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9062085&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyN-DBhCDARIsAFOELTliNgB_UOCtYN8vwFE6_8HdKpevgiz48cVuYY_V8RJRPIHc03xVp88aArjAEALw_wcB)
3. Get min value from the non-zero item, if no item then default is 0 i.e. `min((new_i), default=0)`
4. Append the result of step 3 to to output variable i.e. `mins`

code: -

```
data = [[0, 723, 124,],[4084, 208, 32, 4 ], [ 413, 277, 0, 154], [], [211, 132,0, 54]]
mins = []
for i in data:
    new_i = list(filter(lambda x: x !=0, i))
    mins.append(min((new_i), default=0))
print(mins)
```

Same code with List comprehensive -

```
mins = [ min(filter(lambda x: x !=0, i), default=0)
         for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple variant of the [Vivek Sable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67109468/8227062) answer is

```py
list(map(lambda x: min((val for val in x if val != 0), default=0), data))
```